# Reducing a Boolean function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra

I have the following boolean function:

**f(x,y,z) = xyz + xyz' + xy'z + x'yz + xy'z'**

I could reduce it to the following:

**f(x,y,z) = xy + xy'z + x'yz + xy'z**

Im not sure what to do next, i know it can be reduced to x + yz but im really lost.

Thanks for the help and im sorry if im not using the traditional notations

Comment: $x'yz$ is repeating twice in that statement!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\color{red}{xyz+xyz'}+\color{blue}{xy'z}+x'yz+\color{blue}{xy'z'}&=\color{red}{xy(z+z')}+\color{blue}{xy'(z+z')}+x'yz\\
&=xy+xy'+x'yz\\
&=x(y+y')+x'yz\\
&=x+x'yz\\
&\overset{*}=(x+xyz)+x'yz\\
&=x+(x+x')yz\\
&=x+yz
\end{align*}$$

The starred step uses one of the absorption rules: $x=x+xu$ for any $u$.

Comment: Nice use of color in the answer.  You could of duplicated xyz in initial and reduced $\color{green}{xyz + x'yz}$ at start.